# Golang struct inheritance not working as intended?

Tags: go

Check out [this sandbox](https://play.golang.org/p/elIHgHAZjT)

When declaring a struct that inherits from a different struct:

```
type Base struct {
    a string
    b string
}

type Something struct {
    Base
    c string
}
```

Then calling functions specifying values for the inherited values gives a compilation error:

```
f(Something{
    a: "letter a",
    c: "letter c",
})
```

The error message is: `unknown Something field 'a' in struct literal`.

This seems highly weird to me. Is this really the intended functionality?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Golang doesn't provide the typical notion of inheritance. What you are accomplishing here is embedding.

It does not give the outer struct the fields of the inner struct but instead allows the outer struct to access the fields of the inner struct.

In order to create the outer struct `Something` you need to give its fields which include the inner struct `Base`

In your case:

```
Something{Base: Base{a: "letter a"}, c: "letter c"}
```

Comment: one good consequence is that if you do json.Marshal you will get the {a, b, c} structure you want

Comment: What're the differences from `type Something struct {
    Base Base
    c string
}`?

Answer (score 11):

You need to explicitly create Base field like that

```
f(Something{
    Base: Base{a: "letter a"},
    c:    "letter c",
})
```

Go has no inheritance, it is just composition.

Comment: Composition is the ubiquitous computer science term, worth pointing out though that the actual Go feature being utilized here is embedding.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal True, but I intentionally used this wording, because of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Answer (score 5):

You have to actually instantiate the embedded struct as well. Just so you know this isn't inheritance technically, no such feature exists in Go. It's called embedding. It just hoists fields and methods from the embedded type to the embeddors scope. So anyway, the composite literal instantiation you're trying to do would look like this;

```
f(Something{
    Base: Base{a: "a", b: "b"},
    c:    "c",
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the example from [Go by Example: Struct Embedding](https://gobyexample.com/struct-embedding), the trick part is that we need to explicitly initialize the embedded struct, but we can directly access the embedded fields.

```golang
type base struct {
    num int
}
type container struct {
    base
    str string
}
// initialize the embedding explicitly
co := container{
    base: base{
       num: 1,
    },
    str: "some name",
}
// however, the embedded field can be accessed directly
fmt.Printf("co={num: %v, str: %v}\n", co.num, co.str)
// this also works
fmt.Println("also num:", co.base.num)
```