# Modifying a struct type inside vendor files

Tags: go, struct

I have to modify a struct inside a vendor file. Suppose this is how the struct is inside the vendor file

```
type sampleStruct struct {
    sampleStringvar1       string
    sampleStringvar2       string
}
```

I need to add one more field to it like this

```
type sampleStruct struct {
    sampleStringvar1       string
    sampleStringvar2       string
    sampleBoolVar          bool
}
```

How can I achieve this? Is it good practise to modify vendor variables like this? If not what is the best way to do this?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is go's means of "inheritance". Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34644117/golang-struct-inheritance-not-working-as-intended

Comment: "*Is it good practise to modify vendor variables*" - no. "*what is the best way to do this?*" - none. Need another solution entirely.

Comment: This is not exposed. so anyway you can not use this in your application

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to fork a vendored library and replace it with your own, the best practice would be, in your project, to use a wrapper.

The wrapper object would be struct:

- referencing a `sampleStruct` instance
- with a `sampleBoolVar` boolean

That is:

```golang
type MySampleStruct {
    ss            *sampleStruct 
    sampleBoolVar bool
}
```

That way, you can benefit from `sampleBoolVar` while the vendored library keep using a `sampleStruct` as usual.

But, [blackgreen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4108803/blackgreen) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67877217/modifying-a-struct-type-inside-vendor-files/67940280#comment120096100_67940280):

> How would you be able to reference an unexported struct, as `sampleStruct` appears to be, outside its own package?

This is correct, and the aforementioned suggestion is *not* about exposing a private variable, but about managing that variable yourself, based on what you see from `sampleStruct`.
Depending on the library behavior, that might not be possible.

Comment: How would you be able to reference an unexported struct, as `sampleStruct` appears to be, outside its own package?

Comment: @blackgreen The idea was more to manage that variable yourself, not to expose a private variable that (and I agree with you), you wouldn't have access anyway. I have edited the answer to reference your comment  and make that clearer.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it good practise to modify vendor variables like this?

Absolutely not.

> If not what is the best way to do this?

Fork the vendor module and reference the fork with a `replace` directive in your `go.mod`.